# Cython : Object of type ... has no attribute

Tags: c++, cython

**The Context**

I am working in a project that wraps some C++ functions and classes with corresponding Cython code.

In particular, I have a function that is member of a Cython class in a file called `meta_edm.pyx` whose definition reads like this:

```
# meta_edm.pyx
def integrate( self , meta_beta , num_MC_steps , ground_truth_partition , size_partition_pool = None , verbose = False ):

    cdef Partition * ptr_ground_truth_partition
    cdef RunningStats * ptr_rs_NMI_gt
    cdef RunningStats * ptr_rs_AMI_gt
    cdef RunningStats * ptr_rs_NMI_sg
    cdef RunningStats * ptr_rs_AMI_sg
    cdef RunningStats * ptr_rs_energy
    cdef int l
    cdef int ii

    ptr_ground_truth_partition = new Partition( len( ground_truth_partition ) )
    ptr_rs_NMI_gt = new RunningStats()
    ptr_rs_AMI_gt = new RunningStats()
    ptr_rs_NMI_sg = new RunningStats()
    ptr_rs_AMI_sg = new RunningStats()
    ptr_rs_energy = new RunningStats()

    for l , part in enumerate( ground_truth_partition ):
        for i in part:
            ii = self._edm.node_enum( i )
            # --- PAY ATTENTION TO THIS LINE ---
            ptr_ground_truth_partition.change_label_of_element( ii , l )

    if size_partition_pool is None:
        size_partition_pool = self._c_edm.G().num_nodes()

    self._c_meta_edm.integrate( meta_beta , num_MC_steps , deref( ptr_ground_truth_partition ) , size_partition_pool , deref( ptr_rs_NMI_gt ) , deref( ptr_rs_AMI_gt ) , deref( ptr_rs_NMI_sg ) , deref( ptr_rs_AMI_sg ) , deref( ptr_rs_energy ) , verbose )

    rs_NMI_gt = {}
    rs_AMI_gt = {}
    rs_NMI_sg = {}
    rs_AMI_sg = {}
    rs_energy = {}

    rs_NMI_gt[ 'mean' ] = ptr_rs_NMI_gt.mean();
    rs_AMI_gt[ 'mean' ] = ptr_rs_AMI_gt.mean();
    rs_NMI_sg[ 'mean' ] = ptr_rs_NMI_sg.mean();
    rs_AMI_sg[ 'mean' ] = ptr_rs_AMI_sg.mean();
    rs_energy[ 'mean' ] = ptr_rs_energy.mean();

    rs_NMI_gt[ 'std' ] = ptr_rs_NMI_gt.std();
    rs_AMI_gt[ 'std' ] = ptr_rs_AMI_gt.std();
    rs_NMI_sg[ 'std' ] = ptr_rs_NMI_sg.std();
    rs_AMI_sg[ 'std' ] = ptr_rs_AMI_sg.std();
    rs_energy[ 'std' ] = ptr_rs_energy.std();

    rs_NMI_gt[ 'sem' ] = ptr_rs_NMI_gt.sem();
    rs_AMI_gt[ 'sem' ] = ptr_rs_AMI_gt.sem();
    rs_NMI_sg[ 'sem' ] = ptr_rs_NMI_sg.sem();
    rs_AMI_sg[ 'sem' ] = ptr_rs_AMI_sg.sem();
    rs_energy[ 'sem' ] = ptr_rs_energy.sem();

    rs_NMI_gt[ 'min' ] = ptr_rs_NMI_gt.min();
    rs_AMI_gt[ 'min' ] = ptr_rs_AMI_gt.min();
    rs_NMI_sg[ 'min' ] = ptr_rs_NMI_sg.min();
    rs_AMI_sg[ 'min' ] = ptr_rs_AMI_sg.min();
    rs_energy[ 'min' ] = ptr_rs_energy.min();

    rs_NMI_gt[ 'max' ] = ptr_rs_NMI_gt.max();
    rs_AMI_gt[ 'max' ] = ptr_rs_AMI_gt.max();
    rs_NMI_sg[ 'max' ] = ptr_rs_NMI_sg.max();
    rs_AMI_sg[ 'max' ] = ptr_rs_AMI_sg.max();
    rs_energy[ 'max' ] = ptr_rs_energy.max();

    rs_NMI_gt[ 'num_samples' ] = ptr_rs_NMI_gt.num_samples();
    rs_AMI_gt[ 'num_samples' ] = ptr_rs_AMI_gt.num_samples();
    rs_NMI_sg[ 'num_samples' ] = ptr_rs_NMI_sg.num_samples();
    rs_AMI_sg[ 'num_samples' ] = ptr_rs_AMI_sg.num_samples();
    rs_energy[ 'num_samples' ] = ptr_rs_energy.num_samples();

    del ptr_rs_energy;
    del ptr_rs_AMI_sg;
    del ptr_rs_NMI_sg;
    del ptr_rs_AMI_gt;
    del ptr_rs_NMI_gt;
    del ptr_ground_truth_partition;

    return rs_NMI_gt , rs_AMI_gt , rs_NMI_sg , rs_AMI_sg , rs_energy
```

Additionally, I have a corresponding `meta_edm.pxd` file containing, among other things, the code:

```
# meta_edm.pxd
cdef extern from "cpp_partition.h":
    cdef cppclass Partition:

        Partition( int size ) except +
        #~Partition()

        int  size()
        int  num_active_labels()
        int  label_count( int l )
        int  total_count()
        bool is_label_active( int l )
        int  label_of_element( int i )
        void change_label_of_element( int i , int new_l )
```

and, there is a corresponding `cpp_partition.h` file where the class `Partition` is defined.

**The Problem**

When I try to compile this, I get the following error:

```
cythoning ExternalDegreeModel/meta_edm.pyx to ExternalDegreeModel/meta_edm.cpp

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
        ptr_rs_energy = new RunningStats()

        for l , part in enumerate( ground_truth_partition ):
            for i in part:
                ii = self._edm.node_enum( i )
                ptr_ground_truth_partition.change_label_of_element( ii , l )
                                     ^
------------------------------------------------------------

ExternalDegreeModel/meta_edm.pyx:161:42: Object of type 'Partition' has no attribute 'change_label_of_element'
building 'ExternalDegreeModel.meta_edm' extension
```

I am not sure if Python is interpreting `ptr_ground_truth_partition` as a Python object, or if it is interpreting it as a pointer to a C++ object. But, in any case, this is weird since `Partition` seems to be properly declared as a C++ class in the `meta_edm.pxd` file together with its member function `change_label_of_element`.

I have tried many things to solve this problem and I couldn't find a way. Any ideas?

Comment: When I add `from libcpp cimport bool` to the pxd file and comment out the `RunningStats` (which you don't provide a definition of) it works for me (at least past that line)

Comment: I can add the definition of `RunningStats`, if needed. It is a C++ class that it is used without problems in other parts of the code. The project as a whole is "big". It contains many files. I just intended to summarize the source of the problem into a brief exposition but, if needed I can add the rest of the code. Now, regarding your experiment, it is weird that it compiles without the source code in `partition.h`. Can you be more explicit on what you mean by "it works for me"?

Comment: By "it works for me" I mean "Cython seems to run beyond this line". I didn't try compiling the generated c code which would be where the header would be needed. If I were you I'd actually take stuff out: cut it down to the smallest version of this that you still get the error on and post that version completely. Don't worry about the headers since you're only running Cython and not compiling the generated c.

Comment: Since I need to move forward, I have made extensive changes and the question may not be relevant anymore. I just posted the issue hoping for somebody to have had the same or an analogous problem. What is relevant, perhaps, is that the compilation error reported by Cython is not very helpful but confusing. It seems one of those "wholes" where the error is not appropriately informative. In fact, I have used a similar code in other part of the project and it runs. If possible, I can post how the new code looks like.

Comment: No worries. I don't think the new code is likely to be very helpful to anyone else without knowing where the problem is (and it doesn't sound worth trying to track down the problem right now) so I'd leave it.